# If you have a set of symptoms, is there an online way to assess the probability of having Covid-19?

Tags: covid-19

I volunteered with doctors and nurses this weekend on a special project and now I'm home with possible COVID-19 symptoms.  I was closely working in person with around 500 medical personnel in New York City, on Saturday and Sunday.

I currently have unexplained lower back pain, fluctuating body temperature (hot and cold), and a cough that's slowly getting worse.

I took NyQuil Severe Flu tablets, drank some orange juice and am in bed now.

I don't have difficulty breathing at the moment, so I don't want to escalate and utilize emergency services.

Is there a way to triage my symptoms before going to see my family doctor?

Comment: Personal medical advice questions are off-topic here. You should rely on guidance from public health authorities like the CDC https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/if-you-are-sick/steps-when-sick.html and your own physician.

Comment: Repeat to yourself "I cannot get Covid-19, no, no way I am getting it, that's not for me" and then watch your favorite program haha:)

Answer (score 1):

Your family doctors may well be overwhelmed at present and may not be able to immediately assess you.  There are some things you can do at home.

Since many Covid-19 patients in New Zealand with mild symptoms are being sent home to self isolate, and the majority of people (80%) with covid-19 will improve with just home care, then there are online AI based tools to help you with the decision of when to contact your family practitioner, or, failing that attend hospital.

This is one developed by the CDC and Apple.  See https://www.apple.com/covid19

Comment: Thank you sir for you answer +1